# React JS, HTML audio tag not loading music file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using create-react-app I created app, the browser `audio` tag not loading mp3 file.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

  <audio controls src="Kalimba.mp3">
        Your browser does not support the
        <code>audio</code> element.
      </audio>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

file structure is attached as image.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mp3 to work you need to add the type as well. and you need to use the **require** method in react

Here **require** is used for static imports, Which can be images, videos , audios

**./** => Used for current directory

```
 <audio
  controls
  src={require("./Kalimba.mp3")}
  type="audio/mpeg"
 />
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if `mp3` will be supported out of the box but one option according [to docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files) **could be**:

```js
import React from 'react';
import file from './foobar.mp3'; // Tell webpack this JS script uses this file
console.log(file); // /foobar.84287d09.mp3
function Foobar() {
  // Import result is the URL of your file
  return (<audio controls src={file}>
    Your browser does not support the
    <code>audio</code> element.
  </audio>);
}
export default Foobar;
```

Another approach is to [put your `mp3` file to `public` folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder) and then:

```js
render() {
  // Note: this is an escape hatch and should be used sparingly!
  // Normally we recommend using `import` for getting asset URLs
  return (<audio controls src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/foobar.mp3'}>
    Your browser does not support the
    <code>audio</code> element.
  </audio>);
}
```